# jira/tomcat logs "too short" - shows "... 191 more" at tail of log

Tags: tomcat, debian, jira

I have an instance of Apache JIRA (v6.3 currently) running on Tomcat on a 
linode Debian 8 (Jessie) server.

I've enabled the API and am trying to create an issue through it, but I get a `500 Internal Server Error` in response. I looked at the `catalina.out` file and I can see the error come in, but the tail of it looks like this:

```
at com.atlassian.jira.rest.v2.issue.IssueInputParametersAssembler$IssueInputParametersBuilder.buildForCreate(IssueInputParametersAssembler.java:258)
at com.atlassian.jira.rest.v2.issue.IssueInputParametersAssembler.makeCreateAssembler(IssueInputParametersAssembler.java:122)
at com.atlassian.jira.rest.v2.issue.CreateIssueResource.createIssue(CreateIssueResource.java:52)
at com.atlassian.jira.rest.v2.issue.IssueResource.createIssue(IssueResource.java:657)
... 191 more
```

Does anyone know what the "191 more" means or how I can expand it? I think most of the good bits of the log are in those "191 more" lines/errors. Is this a Tomcat setting?

Comment: you're looking at stack trace. Usually the most important information is on the top of stack trace and therefore it makes sense to truncate the rest.

Comment: @Robert, thanks for the reply. It seems to tell me there is something wrong with the project and or issueType but I can't tell exactly what. This is why I was hoping to see what those other 191 lines held.

Comment: and what's the top most line of that stack trace?

Comment: The "191 more" usually happens when you have several exceptions chained together, where each of the exceptions share a whole bunch of stack elements (because only one exception is the root, the the others wrapped and re-threw the exception during exception-handling), so repeating them would only take up unnecessary space. Read the whole stack trace, and you can probably see those other 191 lines attached to another exception in the chain.

Comment: Trust me, you don't care what are those stack frames - usually filters and other servlet engine related stuff. As @Robert mentioned, there are a few lines before the beginning of the stack trace, that is the Message in the exception. Take a look at that.

Comment: @Koshinae, yeah, you're both right. The important bits were actually up further and I thought it was unrelated stuff.

It's slightly a pebkac but it looks like there were internal jira errors after all of that. I had trouble creating issues on the frontend. I had carelessly updated some plugins that I think cause the brokenness. I'm in the progress of updating jira core.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz, yeah, that seems to be the case here. I should have read the logging docs a bit closer.